# Matlab, parallel computing and Amazon EC2

Tags: matlab, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, parallel-processing

I'm completely new to Amazon EC2. I have read the website documentation but I'm still confused.

At the moment I'm estimating my model using Matlab-r2014b. In my Matlab code I use parallel computing ("parfor") on the local cluster. I run my model through the HPC of my University which allows me to access 1 node with 40GB of memory and 12 cores.

My questions are the following:

(1) Does Amazon EC2 offer a machine with more than 40GB of memory and 12 cores where I can run my Matlab code?

(2) Prices and instructions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, yes, the c3.8xlarge instance type is available with 60GB of ram and 32 cores.

Per hour pricing is available here: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/ along with all the other sizes and options.